# R: to move files based on file name

Tags: r

I am looking on a way to move files from one folder to another based on a grouping trait. Say that I have directories called fruit_apple/, fruit_orange/, fruit_lemon/. And a file that states the classification of each fruit like below.

```
classification <- matrix(c('apple', 'non-citrus', 'banana','non-citrus',  'lemon', 'citrus'), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(classification) <- c('fruit','class')
```

Is it possible to create a function that moves the directories from the source to an output directory by class? For instance, fruit_apple/ would be moved to non-citrus/fruit_apple.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Hi, I feel like you could combine `apply()` and `file.copy()` to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested in my comment, it it possible to do something like:

```
apply(classification, 1, function(x) file.copy(from = paste0("./", x[1], ".txt"), to = paste0("./", x[2], "/", x[1], ".txt")))
```

`apply()` with argument `MARGIN = 1` operates by rows of `classification`.
Then a custom function uses the information from the row (`x`) to feed the arguments of the function `file.copy()`.

To make it easier, I have used a RStudio project so I could use relative path `./`. Folders citrus and non-citrus were manually created before running the code.

Starting situation:

```
C:.
|   apple.txt
|   banana.txt
|   lemon.txt
|   starttree.txt
|   testR.Rproj
|   
+---citrus
\---non-citrus
```

End result:

```
C:.
|   apple.txt
|   banana.txt
|   lemon.txt
|   Resultant.txt
|   testR.Rproj
|   
+---citrus
|       lemon.txt
|       
\---non-citrus
        apple.txt
        banana.txt
```

If you want to also remove the files after copying them, you can add `file.remove(paste0("./", x[1], ".txt"))` to the custom function inside `apply`.

Comment: Thank you for that help. It seems to work with files but folders. Is it possible to move entire folders based on the classification file?

Comment: I got it using: `apply(classification, 1, function(x) R.utils::copyDirectory(from = paste0("./", x[1], "./"), to = paste0("./", x[2], "/")))` . Thanks for leading me there!